# Break or Crack the code

Tags: word-choice, difference

He tried to break/crack the code to the safe.

Is "break" and "crack" equally natural here?

Comment: You could do some research on this. Right?

Comment: I have, but I'm still not sure, so that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @gkjayo  Do you know how to use google ngram viewer? Check it out. It shows "break" about 1.5 times more common, so it is slightly more natural.

Comment: You can google: break the code and then crack the code. Look at the numbers and contexts. They are both the same. But you needed to have posted examples here to show your effort. :)